# Fortify Modify PasswordResetLinkController

Tags: laravel-8, fortify, forgot-password, laravel-jetstream, laravel-fortify

How I can add captcha Required from reset-password page? I seen there is a `PasswordResetLinkController`, and it have following code:

```
public function store(Request $request): Responsable
    {
        $request->validate([Fortify::email() => 'required|email']);
        ...
    }
```

What I need to do is only add new line `$request->validate( 'captcha' => 'required']);`.

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer,

What i do is just copy all fortify routes and paste it to `../routes/web.php` and modify the route name to use the new one